# This button's "padding" makes no sense

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a button with a red border thats in the bottom and in the middle, but, its padding doesn't let me! You can see with the border, its like 100% width, it makes no sense.

Ive tried everything, the only "solution" i found, was to set the margins to something like 200px, but the hitbox is still massive in the x axis, if someone knows what might becausing this i'd appreciate an answer, thank you!!

HTML:

```
<div class="message">
  <h1>NA CONJUGAÇÃO DO COMPROMISSO, DO ACOMPANHAMENTO E DA ATENÇÃO.</h1>
  <h3>A colaboração de todos é fundamental para a concretização dos pressupostos de uma escola que todos queremos.</h3>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <a href="example.com">
    <div class="ano-letivo">Ano Letivo</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 80px 300px 5px;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px black;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px black;
}

.ano-letivo {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(255, 69, 59);
}
```

How it looks: (except background)
[image: The red button]

Comment: You are using **div** element for button which has **display: block** - meaning it will get 100% of the available width. Try changing it to span or button element

Comment: @frigidero or you can simply add `display: inline` to your button

Comment: Setting it to a button or span didnt work, nor adding "display: inline", adding "width: fit-content;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;" did work tho, BUT, the hitbox remains as big. (setting margin to 0 makes the button move to the left)

Answer (score 1):

A commenter correctly points out that you should probably change your element from `div` to `button`. However, if for some reason you need to keep the element as-is, adding the following CSS rules should center it:

```css
width: fit-content;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
```

Here's a demo:

```css
h1 {
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 80px 300px 5px;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px black;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px black;
}

.ano-letivo {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(255, 69, 59);
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="example.com">
    <div class="ano-letivo">Ano Letivo</div>
  </a>
</div>
```